# Prove a graph is planar

Tags: graph-theory

I am kinda new to graph theory so I appreciate any suggestion or hint to approach this question. Thank you!

Suppose a graph G does not have K2,2 as a subgraph. Suppose also that G has exactly 4 vertices of degree 4 , and all other vertices have degree less than 4. Explain why G must be planar.

Comment: The theorem goes "a graph is planar if and only if it does not have a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ minor," so using this information, can we conclude that $G$ does not have either of these graphs as a minor?

Comment: Sorry I still can't figure it out. So I am supposed to prove that G is not homeomorphic to K3,3 and K5?

Comment: To be specific, you must prove that $G$ does **not have a subgraph** homeomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: How can I prove that? Can you give a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for such a graph to be non-planar. Take $K_{3,3}$, add two edges, one to each partite set, then subdivide all edges. The resulting graph is non-planar (it has $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor), has the degree sequence desired, and has girth 6, so it has no $K_{2,2} = C_4$ subgraph.